# showing unused wordpress tags

Tags: wordpress, foreach, tags

I'm trying to make a list of all `tags` i added in wordpress, but it only shows the ones that are already used. Same thing happens with the `categories`.
I tried to make 1 post with all `tags` and `categories` and just not publish it, but all `tags` and `categories` only show up when published.

```
foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    $tags= $tag->name;
    $naampje1 = $tags . get_the_ID();
    echo $tags. ': ';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'. $naampje1 .'">';
    echo str_repeat('&nbsp;', 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$tags = get_tags();
   $html = '<div class="post_tags">';

   foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    if(tag->count <= 0){
     $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
     $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
     $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
    }
   }
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more information please visit,

- [Function Reference/get tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags)

Answer (score 0):

thnx sunil for the answer

apparently wordpress hides the empty terms, these lines work.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'post_tag', array(
'hide_empty' => false,
) );

$terms = get_terms( 'category', array(
'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```